# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined when working with VuePress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuepress

I'm trying to create documentation for my component library, and I'm running into `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` when I try to get VuePress running in development. I'm not sure how to resolve this.

This library is scaffolded using [vue-sfc-rollup](https://github.com/team-innovation/vue-sfc-rollup)

```js
// enhanceApp.js
import ComponentLibrary from './../../src/entry.js'

export default ({ Vue, options, router, siteData }) => {
    Vue.use(ComponentLibrary)
}
```

```js
// entry.js
// Import vue components
import * as components from '@/lib-components/index';

// install function executed by Vue.use()
const install = function installVueCharge(Vue) {
  if (install.installed) return;
  install.installed = true;
  Object.entries(components).forEach(([componentName, component]) => {
    Vue.component(componentName, component);
  });
};

// Create module definition for Vue.use()
const plugin = {
  install,
};

// To auto-install on non-es builds, when vue is found
// eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare
/* global window, global */
if ('false' === process.env.ES_BUILD) {
  let GlobalVue = null;
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = window.Vue;
  } else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    GlobalVue = global.Vue;
  }
  if (GlobalVue) {
    GlobalVue.use(plugin);
  }
}
// Default export is library as a whole, registered via Vue.use()
export default plugin;

// To allow individual component use, export components
// each can be registered via Vue.component()
export * from '@/lib-components/index';
```

Edit: I've added my rollup.config.js as this is where `process.env.ES_BUILD` is defined.

```js
// rollup.config.js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import minimist from 'minimist';

// Get browserslist config and remove ie from es build targets
const esbrowserslist = fs.readFileSync('./.browserslistrc')
  .toString()
  .split('\n')
  .filter((entry) => entry && entry.substring(0, 2) !== 'ie');

const argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));

const projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

const baseConfig = {
  input: 'src/entry.js',
  plugins: {
    preVue: [
      alias({
        resolve: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
        entries: {
          '@': path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src'),
        },
      }),
    ],
    replace: {
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
      'process.env.ES_BUILD': JSON.stringify('false'),
    },
    vue: {
      css: true,
      template: {
        isProduction: true,
      },
    },
    babel: {
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
    },
  },
};

// ESM/UMD/IIFE shared settings: externals
// Refer to https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
const external = [
  // list external dependencies, exactly the way it is written in the import statement.
  // eg. 'jquery'
  'vue',
];

// UMD/IIFE shared settings: output.globals
// Refer to https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#output-globals for details
const globals = {
  // Provide global variable names to replace your external imports
  // eg. jquery: '$'
  vue: 'Vue',
};

// Customize configs for individual targets
const buildFormats = [];
if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'es') {
  const esConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      file: 'dist/vue-charge.esm.js',
      format: 'esm',
      exports: 'named',
    },
    plugins: [
      replace({
        ...baseConfig.plugins.replace,
        'process.env.ES_BUILD': JSON.stringify('true'),
      }),
      ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
      vue(baseConfig.plugins.vue),
      babel({
        ...baseConfig.plugins.babel,
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              targets: esbrowserslist,
            },
          ],
        ],
      }),
      commonjs(),
    ],
  };
  buildFormats.push(esConfig);
}

if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'cjs') {
  const umdConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      compact: true,
      file: 'dist/vue-charge.ssr.js',
      format: 'cjs',
      name: 'VueCharge',
      exports: 'named',
      globals,
    },
    plugins: [
      replace(baseConfig.plugins.replace),
      ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
      vue({
        ...baseConfig.plugins.vue,
        template: {
          ...baseConfig.plugins.vue.template,
          optimizeSSR: true,
        },
      }),
      babel(baseConfig.plugins.babel),
      commonjs(),
    ],
  };
  buildFormats.push(umdConfig);
}

if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'iife') {
  const unpkgConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      compact: true,
      file: 'dist/vue-charge.min.js',
      format: 'iife',
      name: 'VueCharge',
      exports: 'named',
      globals,
    },
    plugins: [
      replace(baseConfig.plugins.replace),
      ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
      vue(baseConfig.plugins.vue),
      babel(baseConfig.plugins.babel),
      commonjs(),
      terser({
        output: {
          ecma: 5,
        },
      }),
    ],
  };
  buildFormats.push(unpkgConfig);
}

// Export config
export default buildFormats;
```

Comment: where does `process.env.ES_BUILD` appear in your webpack.config.js (or other build tool)?

Comment: it appears in my rollup.config.js

Comment: Can you please add your `rollup.config.js` to the main question?

Comment: I've added my `rollup.config.js` above

Answer (score 0):

`process.env` is removed, you can use `import.meta.env` instead.

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/commit/8ad7ecd1029bdc0b47e55877db10ac630829c7e5